# Definition of local complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

In Hartshorne, there is the following definition of a “local complete intersection”:

[image]

Now, what does “locally generated by $r$ elements at every point" mean?

I think one of the following:

1. $X$ can be covered by affine open sets $\{U_i＝\operatorname{Spec} A_i\}$, such that ideal $I_i\subset A_i$ (corresponding to $\mathscr{I}_i\subset \mathscr{O}_{U_i}$) can be generated $r$ elements.
2. For all $x\in X$, the ideal $\mathscr{I}_x\subset \mathscr{O}_{x,X}$ can be generated $r$ elements.

Which is the correct definition? Or are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Your guess that these are equivalent is a good one - have you explored that at all, say by trying to prove that they are in fact equivalent? (A brief typographical comment: please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it produces better spacing. I've made the upgrade in your post for you this time.)

Comment: Thank you for editing my bad English. I can’t proof there are equivalent.

Comment: If you add some information about your attempts to your post with an [edit], I'd be glad to help you finish the proof.